# Error adding SQLite plugin for Ionic framework via git clone

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to add SQLite plugin to my Ionic project using this command

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git
```

And here is an output:

> Fetching plugin
>   "https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git" via git
>   clone Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git via git.
>   Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
>         Error: C:\msysgit\bin\git.exe: Command failed with exit code 128
>   Error output: Cloning into
>   'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1459420827450'...

I have a firewall, so I've already set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try setting the proxy in the npm. You can set the proxy in the npm something like this

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

The port 8080 and company name would vary.

If it does not work, check for Git install. (Set the proxy for git as well) and then add plugin.

If all else fails try  `cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`on the CLI.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I used the following commands: `npm config set proxy http://user:password@url:port` and `npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@url:port`

Comment: Ok , i belive u have git installed , what this plugin is doing is it it fetching it from the git repository and not from npm,could u try to work with git behind a proxy .'git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080' where proxyuser to your proxy user
proxypwd to your proxy password
proxy.server.com to the URL of your proxy server
8080 to the proxy port configured on your proxy server

Comment: could u try running cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage instead of

Comment: Tried the last comment. It works! Thanks for you advice. Please update your answer and I'll accept it